# My Uuntu keeps random and total freeze

Tags: 18.04

There are moments with and moment calm...
Right now, it's a hard moment.

My Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS keeps freeze.
`apt update && apt upgrade` is ok.

I edit the etc/default/grub file as advised in another thread...
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=2"`

It didnt do the trick.

When it freeze, I can't do anything. Neither Alt+Sys+K nor go to tty3.

Here's some info.
Let me know if you have any idea... with holidays ending, and University now... It's pretty annoying to reboot my computer 5 times an hour.
Thanks !

ACER Aspire E5

```
brieucdug@sildenafil:~$ sudo lshw -C display -numeric
[sudo] password for brieucdug: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:F31]
       vendor: Intel Corporation [8086]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0e
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:91 memory:90000000-903fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:2050(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff


brieucdug@sildenafil:~$ lspci -nnk | egrep -iA3 "VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [8086:0f31] (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display [1025:087f]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

brieucdug@sildenafil:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       3,4Gi       2,9Gi       553Mi       1,3Gi       3,4Gi
Swap:         7,9Gi       113Mi       7,8Gi
```

Comment: Baytrail seems to be behaving with 19.04 kernel 5.0 that I am on.  Have not used 18.04 enough to see, but 15.10 was bad also.  See this link to see if you are on kernel 5 and how to update.  https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-hwe-kernel/

Comment: I've currently activate the dist-upgrade to give 19.04 a hit. I'm on Kernel 4.15.0-62.

I'll upgrade to K5 if the dist-upgrade doesnt and I'll give some update here. I shall need few days of "testing" to know it the issue will be resolved I guess.

Thanks a lot for your tips !

Comment: Good luck, check grub after to make sure cstate made it through.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `free -h`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: I'm coming with some news with the Kernel 5.0.0-27 ! No more freezes, and it works much better ! Thanks a lot

@heynnemma
```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       3,4Gi       2,9Gi       553Mi       1,3Gi       3,4Gi
Swap:         7,9Gi       113Mi       7,8Gi
```